# What does "Remuneration: Expenses" mean in an internship description?

Tags: internship, fees

While reading an internship description it mentions *Remuneration:Expenses* with 3 months duration. What is the interpretation of this? Does it mean if I get accepted I won't get paid? In general, is it worth applying for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you will be reimbursed for your living and travel expenses, but you will not receive a salary.

As for the wisdom of taking such an internship, that's impossible for us to judge in the context of your career.

Comment: The context and responsibilities are closely related to my background and in the area I would like to follow, so I think it's hard to say no. Maybe this will be the first step to a better internship in future years.

Comment: You would likely only receive living expenses if you are expected to relocate for the role.

Comment: You need to clarify with them which expenses they will reimburse, mind you.